# Detect SQL database changes

Tags: c#, sql, listener, service-broker, sqldependency

Consider this example:

```
INSERT INTO [Table] (column1)
SELECT value1
```

If I were to execute this command in SSMS, in regards to a c# forms application, what would I need to do in order to recognize this event? Something as simple as the application displaying a `MessageBox` when this event occurs. I just can't seem to work this one out or find any helpful data on it. I have attempted to use `SqlDependency` but am not having any luck. If that is the path I need to go down, can anyone help me out with understanding the concept a little better?

Comment: if I understand you, you want to trigger an event in your c# app when your sql server runs an insert select?

Comment: @paqogomez Correct! Kind of like a trigger in ssms, I want a trigger in C#

Comment: You want to detect when something changes in the database from a C# app?  SQL Server doesn't push notifications so you're going to have to poll something.  One thing you could do is add an `INSERT TRIGGER` where needed that logs to an audit table and `SELECT` from that.

Comment: SQL Server supports writing CLR-based triggers. That means you can run C# code when something is inserted. I would recommend you use this and have the trigger send an event to the app in some way.

Comment: When something changes (update) or when something is inserted? What happened when you tried SQLDependency?

Comment: @PaulZahra Primarily `Insert`, but I'd be happy just to make the trigger fire at this point.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to detect changes and not just inserts you could achieve this using [SQL Dependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Have you read and tried the example in the link?

[Heres a nice 'tutorial / example' that works and runs you through the basics](http://dimarzionist.wordpress.com/2009/04/01/how-to-make-sql-server-notifications-work/).

[Heres a nice overview of Query Notifications.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

- The low-level implementation is provided by the SqlNotificationRequest class that exposes server-side functionality, enabling you to execute a command with a notification request.
- The high-level implementation is provided by the SqlDependency class, which is a class that provides a high-level abstraction of notification functionality between the source application and SQL Server, enabling you to use a dependency to detect changes in the server. In most cases, this is the simplest and most effective way to leverage SQL Server notifications capability by managed client applications using the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server.
- In addition, Web applications built using ASP.NET 2.0 or later can use the SqlCacheDependency helper classes.

It is as basic as "A SqlDependency object can be associated with a SqlCommand in order to detect when query results differ from those originally retrieved."

You must first [Enable Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172133%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and follow [Creating a Query for Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181122.aspx)

```
void Initialization()
{
    // Create a dependency connection.
    SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, queueName);
}

void SomeMethod()
{
    // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.
    // Create a new SqlCommand object which directly references (no synonyms) the data you want to check for changes.
    using (SqlCommand command=new SqlCommand("SELECT value1 FROM [Table]", connection))
    {
        // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
        SqlDependency dependency=new SqlDependency(command);
        // Maintain the refence in a class member.

        // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
        dependency.OnChange+=new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

        // Execute the command.
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Process the DataReader.
        }
    }
}

// Handler method
void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e )
{
  // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).
}

void Termination()
{
    // Release the dependency.
    SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString, queueName);
}
```

Comment: this does not give me the inserted row

Comment: Try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401057/sqldependency-doesnt-fire-on-row-insertion-or-update-or-delete

Comment: Or something like this ingenious 'service broker listener' https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener