# SqlDependency doesn't fire on row insertion (or update, or delete)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, signalr, sqldependency

After bashing my head against a wall for the next few hours I've slowly started to realise where my problem lays, so let me give you a recap: I'm trying to change a website's string when a row gets inserted into a database, **but for some reason the trigger I've made that tells me when there's been a change into the database doesn't fire at all when an insertion, udpate or whatever happens. The table's Service Broker is on.**

**This is the involved code:**

```
namespace WebApplication.SignalR_Data
{
    public class NotificationRepository
    {
        public NotificationInfo GetData()
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReservationDbContext"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Reservations", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;

                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    return new NotificationInfo { RowCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar(), Date = DateTime.Now };

                }
            }
        }

// This is the method that handles the trigger.
        public void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                NotificationHub.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose that it's not working because of mistakes I've made, but sadly I haven't been able to spot them yet.

Through NotificationHub.Show(); a message is broadcasted to all clients of the website with the updated rowcount and date, but that message is never sent because the trigger doesn't fire. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just getting the dumb question out of the way first: is service broker enabled at the database level? Check sys.databases for is_broker_enabled for your database.

Comment: Have you actually read the documentation for SqlDependency? There are so many errors in your code. Just a few: You can't use COUNT(*) without a GROUP BY (if you checked for errors in the handler you might have noticed this). The dependency need to be restarted after each trigger.

Comment: I found out about that after an hour or so. It works now. Thanks.

Comment: If you solved your problem, could post answer showing how you solved it?

Comment: @krieg I also facing same problem, can yu please help me regarding this. What did you tried to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to register method GetData() again for continue receive event.
Like this:

```
public void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                NotificationHub.Show();
            }
            GetData();
        }
```

Comment: This calls an infinite loop (like some sort of long-polling). Maybe there's a better way? I've checked with the logs and xhr network requests.

Comment: It's not a better way, but in this case, it will work. For avoid infinite loop just add unregister event before call GetData method like this:
 dependency.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

Comment: I tried using SqlTableDependency (different from SqlDependency) and it works without this workaround. Plus, you'll get the object that was altered automatically (whether, INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE).

Comment: SqlTableDependency support notifications triggered by DML executed every 50 milliseconds. Test realized with two client applications concurrently executing 10.000 random insert/update/operation on same table.(https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency).

SqlTableDependency maybe better than SqlDependency. Thanks @johnmikelridzz